# counting occurences of pattern from an input file to match against a huge file

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, grep, python

I have a list of colleges in a text file, and in a separate file I have a list of publications with affiliation. I want to write a script, to check, how many times a publication is repeated and to count the number of times universities has collaborated. My data is below; "p1" is the title of the paper, "Affiliation" are the colleges involved to published it

**Example:-**

**Data**

**UID, Affiliation**

```
p1    "ADPRI, S"
p1    "ADPRI, S"
p2    "ADPRI, S"
p2    "AAC&S, H"
p3    "AAC&S, H"
p3    "HU, USA" 
p3    "Penn, USA"
p4    "AAC&S, H"  
p5    "AAC&S, H"  
p6    "AAC&S, H"  
p7    "AAC&S, H"  
p8    "AU, A"  
p9    "AECI, A"  
p10   "AECI, A" 
p10   "AECI, A"
```

In the above data, paper "p2" is linked to "ADPRI, S" and "AAC&S, H".
Similarly "p3" is linked to colleges "AAC&S, H", "HU, USA", "Penn, USA".
So my script should give a file where the count of number of collaboration is given between two colleges. For above data it will be

**Desired output:**

```
 College_A       College_B       Collaborated
  ADPRI, S       AAC&S, H            2
  HU, USA        Penn, USA           1
  ....
  ....
 so on for all the colleges,
```

**I used sort and uniq command on "column 2", to get the number of colleges, which is list of 797 colleges and my database has more than 20000 papers published by those colleges. My data also has lot of white spaces and special characters. **

PS:- Data is Tab-separated, I have same data in CSV too.

Comment: `p1` has duplicated affiliation, why?

Comment: That means, there are two authors from the same university/college.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gawk` solution.

**Usage:** `./program.awk input.txt`

Also, you can do: `./program.awk input.txt | column -t -s $'\t'` for the pretty displaying, if the alignment is lost.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

function pub_to_aff() {
    for(i in pub_arr) {
        for(j in pub_arr) {
            if(i != j)
                aff_arr[i][j]++;    
        }   
    }   
    delete pub_arr;
}

BEGIN {
    OFS = "\t";
    FS = "\t";
}

$1 != prev_uid {
    prev_uid = $1; 
    pub_to_aff();
}
{
    pub_arr[$2] = 1;
}

END {
    pub_to_aff();
    print "College_A", "College_B", "Collaborated";

    for(i in aff_arr) {
        for(j in aff_arr[i]) {
            print i, j, aff_arr[i][j];          
        }   
    }   
}
```

**Input** - two lines were added for demonstration - to `p3` and `p4`.

```
p1  "ADPRI, S"
p1  "ADPRI, S"
p2  "ADPRI, S"
p2  "AAC&S, H"
p3  "AAC&S, H"
p3  "ADPRI, S"
p3  "HU, USA"
p3  "Penn, USA"
p4  "AAC&S, H"
p4  "ADPRI, S"
p5  "AAC&S, H"
p6  "AAC&S, H"
p7  "AAC&S, H"
p8  "AU, A"
p9  "AECI, A"
p10 "AECI, A"
p10 "AECI, A"
```

**Output**

```
College_A   College_B   Collaborated
"AAC&S, H"  "HU, USA"   1
"AAC&S, H"  "Penn, USA" 1
"AAC&S, H"  "ADPRI, S"  3
"HU, USA"   "AAC&S, H"  1
"HU, USA"   "Penn, USA" 1
"HU, USA"   "ADPRI, S"  1
"Penn, USA" "AAC&S, H"  1
"Penn, USA" "HU, USA"   1
"Penn, USA" "ADPRI, S"  1
"ADPRI, S"  "AAC&S, H"  3
"ADPRI, S"  "HU, USA"   1
"ADPRI, S"  "Penn, USA" 1
```

---

#### EDIT - real data testing.

**Input** - I left only part of your sample.txt content and changed couple of lines for demonstration of script working. Note, if the input file doesn't contain collaborated universities, the script will output the one line only - header.

```
WOS:000355337800046 "ACHARYA NARENDRA DEV COLL, NEW DELHI"
WOS:000355337800046 "ACHARYA NARENDRA DEV COLL, NEW DELHI"
WOS:000355337800046 "ACHARYA PRAFULLA CHANDRA COLL. KOLKATA"
WOS:000328700900001 "ACHARYA PRAFULLA CHANDRA COLL. KOLKATA"
WOS:000338233800012 "ADAMAS INST TECHNOL, KOLKATA"
WOS:000338233800012 "ADARSH MAHAVIDYALAYA DHAMANGAON RAILWAY, AMRAVATI"
WOS:000349637600009 "ADARSH MAHAVIDYALAYA DHAMANGAON RAILWAY, AMRAVATI"
WOS:000314892400031 "ADITYA INST TECHNOL & MANAGEMENT, TEKKALI"
```

**Used command:** `./program.awk sample.txt | column -t -s $'\t'`

**Output**

```
College_A                                            College_B                                            Collaborated
"ADAMAS INST TECHNOL, KOLKATA"                       "ADARSH MAHAVIDYALAYA DHAMANGAON RAILWAY, AMRAVATI"  1
"ACHARYA NARENDRA DEV COLL, NEW DELHI"               "ACHARYA PRAFULLA CHANDRA COLL. KOLKATA"             1
"ACHARYA PRAFULLA CHANDRA COLL. KOLKATA"             "ACHARYA NARENDRA DEV COLL, NEW DELHI"               1
"ADARSH MAHAVIDYALAYA DHAMANGAON RAILWAY, AMRAVATI"  "ADAMAS INST TECHNOL, KOLKATA"                       1
```

Comment: Thank you it, works for the above data, but with minor glitches. 
For example:- in output it displays "Penn   " instead of "Pen, USA", similarly for others, after comma country is missing.
If I apply to my entire dataset only two lines are there in the output.

Comment: @CCC Does the "Penn, USA" string have the tab between `"Penn, ` and `USA"`? I was assumed, that it is a space and the tab is only between `p3` and  `"Penn, USA"`. Because the `p3` is the first column / field and the `"Penn, USA"` is the second column / field. It should not have tabs inside the column string - tabs only for columns delimiting.

Comment: No, there is no tab in between them. But the first column has :(colon) in it. I re-checked there is no tab, but there are multiple white spaces in few rows. 
More sample is below, Example:
WOS:000337466200077 "WMO ARTS & SCI COLL, NORTH K"
WOS:000260369000004 "WAD INST HIM GEO, EHRA DUN"

Since, comment can't be multi-line it looks odd, here each line starts with WOS:

Comment: @CCC My script assumes, that the file has next format: first column (publication), `\t` (tab delimiter), second column (University name), then other columns can be farther. If your real data format differs from this, it wouldn't work. Because it splits file to columns by the tab character. If the extra tab appears somewhere inside first two columns, the script considers it like the additional column.

Comment: @CCC Does your file have the tab character in between `WOS:000337466200077` and `"WMO ARTS...`?

Comment: The real data is same as the one I have posted, at few places instead of just p1, p2 ... it stars with WOS. There is no extra tab between `WOS:000337466200077` and `"WMO ARTS...`. and each line is separated by `\n`

Comment: @CCC But the one tab should be in between two first columns -  `WOS:000337466200077` and `"WMO ARTS...`. Does it present there? Is your file separated by tabs? You can place part of your file (20-30 lines) to the any share service, like google drive, and put the link here. Then our discussion will be more productive.

Comment: Here's the link for the file [ https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jDIcbw-hzS1BILwjnUyIHkVH7kr1QhK3/view ]

Comment: @CCC I tested the script with your `sample.txt` and it works as expected. But `sample.txt` doesn't contain any collaborated universities, so the script outputs nothing, except the header line. I changed some lines, to simulate collaboration and the script output these universities. See the **EDIT** section of my answer.

Comment: After copying the data from above page, I replace " followed by whitespace with \t", then the script is working smoothly. 
So, I checked for tab, extra spaces and other characters which might have creeped in in my original file, but nothing is there. Is the problem something to do with version of awk or bash or something else? 
The script won't work if I take part of the data from the original file, even where collaboration is there!!

Comment: @CCC I use GNU Awk (`gawk`) version 4.1.3

Comment: @CCC Try to add a few collaborated universities into your original `sample.txt` by yourself, not copied from here. Don't change any formatting. Does it works? I did the same and it worked in my case. Why it doesn't work in your case, I don't have assumptions.

Comment: Yes, I did that before, and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

With Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);
use Set::Intersection;

my ( %papers, @colleges );

while (<>) {          
    chomp; 
    my ( $paper, $college ) = m/(\S+)\t"(.+)"/g;

    # normalize college names
    $college =~ s/\s\+/ /go;
    $college =~ s/^\s\+//go;
    $college =~ s/\s\+$//go;

    $papers{$college} //= [];
    push @{ $papers{$college} }, $paper;
}

@colleges = sort keys %papers;
for my $college (@colleges) {
    $papers{$college} = [ uniq sort @{ $papers{$college} } ];
}

print qq(College_A\tCollege_B\tCollaborated\n);
for ( my $i = 0 ; $i < @colleges - 1 ; $i++ ) {
    for ( my $j = $i + 1 ; $j < @colleges ; $j++ ) {
        my $collaborations = scalar get_intersection(
            { -preordered => 1 },
            $papers{ $colleges[$i] },
            $papers{ $colleges[$j] }
        );  
        print $colleges[$i], "\t", $colleges[$j], "\t", $collaborations, "\n"
          if ($collaborations);
    }
}
```

With Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function

import re
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

papers = defaultdict(lambda: set())
for line in sys.stdin:
    paper, college = line.split("\t")
    college = re.sub(r'^"|"$', '', college)
    college = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', college)
    college = re.sub(r'^\s+|\s+$', '', college)
    papers[college].add(paper)

colleges = sorted(papers.keys())

print("College_A\tCollege_B\tCollaborated")
for i in range(len(colleges) - 1):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(colleges)):
        collaborations = len(papers[colleges[i]].intersection(papers[colleges[j]]))
        if collaborations:
            print("%s\t%s\t%d" % (colleges[i], colleges[j], collaborations))
```

Comment: I did perl code.pl but it says Can't locate Set/Intersection.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Set::Intersection module), I am doing that now, but how to give my files as input here?

Comment: For Perl: `script.pl affiliations.txt`, or `script.pl <affiliations.txt`.  For Python: `script.py <affiliations.txt`.

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm. Will you find time to explain it? 
Also, can the same be done using awk/sed/grep?